# How do I capture OpenSSH output on Powershell?

Tags: powershell, ssh, openssh

I SSH'd into FreeBSD server using OpenSSH on PowerShell script. I echo the word "Hello" and I want to capture the returning Hello into PowerShell variable. How can I do that?

```
$ssh = New-Object -ComObject shell.Application;
$ssh = Start-Process -NoNewWindow ssh user@192.168.19.230
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('echo Hello')
$wshell.SendKeys('{Enter}')
```

I have tried `$output = $wshell.SendKeys('{Enter}')` but it didn't get anything.
I searched for ways to capture the output to a file, wasn't successful.

Comment: `$output = & ssh user@192.168.19.230 echo 'Hello'`

Comment: `SendKeys` is a *terrible* way of automating stuff. Do not use it unless being forced at gunpoint.